# Remove multiple lines from text files vb

Tags: vbscript

I want to delete 3 lines from a text file, starting with names test, test2, test3.
The following script that I created just deletes one, how can I set it to delete the 3 lines?

```
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
strFileName = "c:\test.txt"
strCheckForString = UCase("Directory")
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
objTS.Close

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbNewLine)
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)

For Each strLine In arrLines
   If Not(Left(UCase(LTrim(strLine)),Len(strCheckForString)) = strCheckForString) Then  
      objTS.WriteLine strLine    
   End If
Next
```

Comment: You would not ask this question if you understood what the script really does. Also, this is not vb.net, but VBScript.

Comment: Correct answer, i am new at this. I still hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this one string here:

```
strCheckForString = UCase("Directory")
```

(which by the way you can write like this `strCheckForString = "DIRECTORY"`)

You could add other strings like this

```
strCheckForString1 = "AnotherString"
strCheckForString2 = "ThirdString"
```

Then, inside the loop, you need to check if the other strings match, too

```
If Not(Left(UCase(LTrim(strLine)),Len(strCheckForString)) = strCheckForString) AND
   Not(Left(UCase(LTrim(strLine)),Len(strCheckForString1)) = strCheckForString1) AND
   Not(Left(UCase(LTrim(strLine)),Len(strCheckForString2)) = strCheckForString2) Then  
   objTS.WriteLine strLine    
End If
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what this actually does :-)