# Skip some text from line

Tags: vbscript

I need to remove some text from lines:

```
strdir = "C:\texto.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strdir)
Dim arrTxt()
k = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    z = (k+1)
    ReDim Preserve arrTxt(z)
    line = objFile.ReadLine
    arrTxt(k) = line
    k = z
Loop
print Join(arrTxt, ",") 
print (UBound(arrTxt) + 1)
```

My text file `texto.txt`:

```
name=test
correo=test@test.tst
```

I want remove "name=" and "correo=".

Comment: Would you please explain what you are expecting? By *I want skip "name=" and "correo="* do you mean the skipping of the lines starting with "name=" and "correo=", or simply removing "name=" and "correo=", to leave test and test@test.tst in place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript - skip and read lines in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133276/vbscript-skip-and-read-lines-in-text-file)

Comment: Why are any of you answering a clearly duplicate question? Is this the first time someone has asked how to skip a line in a read? Let’s not forget it was tagged with two separate techologies, which makes it “Unclear” at the very least. All this does is fill the site with yet more duplicates and misinformation *(VBScript is not, I repeat not VBA)* making it even harder for people to find a canonical question and associated answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple lines from text files vb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20260549/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart, my question was "Remove some text from line", not skip.
Maybe i wrote about the context, i'm sorry.

Comment: @AntonioBarazarte the processes are the same but regardless you put “Skip” in the question title. The main issue with this question was the ambiguity between whether you wanted a VBS or VBA solution.

Comment: Please provide example output that you are wanting. The description that you've used is unclear as to what *exactly* you are wanting. Some additional input lines would also be helpful.

Comment: @Makyen you realise they already accepted the [tag:vba] [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481686/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, but that doesn't mean that we should not be evaluating the question based on itself. The fact that it's got an accepted answer means it's more likely that we could edit the question into something that's clear and not too broad rather than closing it. However, that doesn't release the OP's responsibility to provide a good question. As always, the point isn't just for the OP to get help, it's to make a repository of Q&A that are helpful to *future* visitors. Those visitors should not need to look at the accepted answer to figure out what the question was actually wanting.

Comment: @Makyen exactly, which this will never be and has already been answered before numerous times. Just needs closing and we can move on.

Comment: @Lankymart I agree that it should be closed in it's current form. That doesn't mean I shouldn't at least *attempt* to get the information into the question which is needed to make it a decent question, even if it ends up being closed as a duplicate after being edited.

Comment: @Makyen but if its a duplicate surely that's wasted effort?

Comment: @Lankymart Perhaps, but I don't agree with the proposed duplicate. IMO, the question is currently unclear/too broad. Given, how I feel the question is most likely intended, I don't really see it as a duplicate of the proposed dup-target.

Comment: @Makyen I think you'll find all three answers have already been given before, whether you agree or not is irrelevant. I also proposed more than one dup target. In VBScript skipping, removing lines in a `TextStream` is either filter out the content you don't want with a `RegExp` or use a `For` / `Do` loop to iterate each line and process the skip / remove that way. Now tell me please, how is this any different to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) - The initial idea is to make the code understandable for a human - the code has the following 3 tasks:

- Read from a file and save the input as a string;
- Manipulate the string (e.g. replace the `name=` and `correo=`;
- Write the manipulated string to a new file;

All these actions are noticeable in the `TestMe()`:

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim readTxt As String
    Dim filePath As String: filePath = "C:\text.txt"

    readTxt = ReadFromFile(filePath)
    readTxt = Replace(readTxt, "name=", "")
    readTxt = Replace(readTxt, "correo=", "")

    WriteToFile filePath, readTxt

End Sub
```

Once the bone above is ready, the two functions `ReadFromFile` and `WriteToFile` are quite handy:

```
Public Function ReadFromFile(path As String) As String

    Dim fileNo As Long
    fileNo = FreeFile

    Open path For Input As #fileNo

    Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
        Dim textRowInput As String
        Line Input #fileNo, textRowInput
        ReadFromFile = ReadFromFile & textRowInput
        If Not EOF(fileNo) Then
            ReadFromFile = ReadFromFile & vbCrLf
        End If
    Loop

    Close #fileNo

End Function

Sub WriteToFile(filePath As String, text As String)

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)
    oFile.Write text
    oFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work, you're just removing the `name=` and `correo=` occurences, not skipping the lines starting with thoses. `MsgBox Replace("name=toto", "name=", "")` will show "toto", not an empty string.

Comment: @Cid - I though that this is what the OP is actually asking for - leaving `test` and `test@test.tst` from the input. He literally wrote "I need remove some text from lines:".

Comment: This means this is unclear what he's asking. For Pankaj and myself, we understood a whole line skipping, not the removal of `name/correo=`.

Comment: @Cid - yup. Still, being able to do any of the two options puts you in a position to easily adjust to the other one.

Comment: @Cid - I agree. I too thought he wanted to remove entire line but Vityata raised a valid question about the clarity on the output

Comment: thanks @Vityata! your code was very helpful!! god bless you!
Sorry for my ambiguous Question, in my native language we speak referenced to the context.

Comment: VBS and VBA are too different technologies, you either using VBS or you’re using VBA. This answer is VBA and doesn’t belong here but should be posted on one of the VBA specific questions *(if it’s not already there)*.

Comment: @Lankymart - the question was tagged with VBA initially, thus the answer belongs here.

Comment: @Vityata it also said VBS in the title and was tagged [tag:vbscript] so at the very least it was “unclear” because it can’t be for both. In which case it should have been flagged as such. Either way, it doesn’t belong here.

Answer (score 3):

@Cid showcased how you can use the power of Split/Join to achieve what you want. I am going to demonstrate how you can harness the power of RegEx to achieve similar result without having to read one line at a time.

Assuming your text file looks like this
[image]

```
strdir = "C:\texto.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strdir)
strContent = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

msgbox RemoveLines(strContent)


Function RemoveLines(str)
  Dim objRegEx
  Set objRegEx = New RegExp
  With objRegEx
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "^name=.*\n|^correo=.*\n"
      .Multiline = True     
  End With
  RemoveLines = objRegEx.Replace(str, "")
End Function
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd [split](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_split.asp) each lines using `=` as delimiter and then, I'd check if the first element is name or correo.

```
strdir = "C:\texto.txt"
Set fso = createobject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strdir)
Dim arrTxt()
k = 0
Do until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    z = (k+1)
    ReDim preserve arrTxt(z)
    line = objFile.ReadLine
    myArray = Split(line, "=")
    If (Not ((UBound(myArray) > 0) AND (myArray(0) = "name" OR myArray(0) = "correo"))) Then
        arrTxt(k) = line
        k = z
    End If
loop
print Join(arrTxt,",") 
print (Ubound(arrTxt) + 1)
```